# get href value by class name regex and php

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

i need to get href value from class name like that.

some one can give me regex to find this class name and get from there the href ?

```
<a href='http://www.tovtoda.co.il/BusinessPage.aspx?b=6973' class="boldOrange"></a>
```

thanks alot

Comment: `some one can give me regex` is not really how SO works. Also you shouldn't really use a regex on HTML/XML. Have you tried a parser?

Comment: use jquery for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `DomDocument` and `XPath`, see here

```
$str = '<a href="http://www.tovtoda.co.il/BusinessPage.aspx?b=6973" class="boldOrange"></a>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$links = $xpath->query('//a[@class="boldOrange"]');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $url = $link->getAttribute('href');
    print $url . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: its not good.
i am using php curl and i need to take this link by class name.